# ¿Por qué el usuario Community sólo vota negativamente?

Tags: discusión

Veo que el usuario [Community](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad?tab=topactivity) (que no es una persona, sinó que sólo se encarga de procesos automáticos) sólo emite votos negativos (aunque no sé cuáles).

¿Eso es normal? ¿Porqué no emite también votos positivos (Y muchos en mi usuario :) )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En realidad no siempre vota negativamente. Hay tres casos en los que el usuario Community se atribuye votos:

1. Cuando una publicación recibe un voto de spam/ofensivo, se añade un voto negativo automáticamente.
2. Cuando un reporte de "muy baja calidad" es considerado útil, se añade un voto negativo automáticamente.
3. Cuando un usuario que había participado mucho en el sitio es borrado, sus votos (tanto positivos como negativos) son transferidos al usuario Community para que no se pierdan.

Comment: Creo que vale la pena agregar que es.so es un sitio muy joven aún ya que no ha cumplido todavía un año así que es poco probable que un usuario que haya participado mucho haya sido borrado y por lo cual, al menos por un tiempo, no va a ser posible ver votos positivos del usuario Comunidad.

Answer (score 2):

Para complementar la pregunta les comparto un par de recortes de los votos emitidos por el usuario Comunidad en el sitio en es.so y del usuario Community en so.

De https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad?tab=topactivity

[image: Recorte de la sección votos emitidos del usuario Comunidad en es.so]

De https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=topactivity

[image: Recorte de la sección votos emitidos del usuario Community en so]