# Cierre con 4 votos: 3 usuarios + ¿el usuario Comunidad?

Tags: soporte, votos-de-cierre, duplicados-exactos, usuario-comunidad

Esta pregunta: [Ampersand delante de método](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/198809/19610) ha sido marcada como *duplicada*. Hasta ahí, todo normal. Pero he observado que solo han sido 3 usuarios *físicos* los que han votado por ello + ¿¿ el usuario [Comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad) ??

Ignoraba la *habilidad* de dicho *usuario* para participar en discusiones trascendentales, tales como marcar o no una pregunta como *duplicada*. Como se ve en [esta otra pregunta de Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/645/por-qu%C3%A9-el-usuario-community-s%C3%B3lo-vota-negativamente), creía que estaba limitado a ciertas tareas organizativas.

No es que me cause un *trauma* ni nada, pero siento curiosidad por este nuevo comportamiento adquirido :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No es el usuario Comunidad, sino que el OP (es decir, quien pregunta) apretó en el cartelito "sí, es una pregunta duplicada".

Me explico:

- Cuando una pregunta recibe algún voto de cierre por duplicada, el OP ve algo así como

  > [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- En ese momento, si el OP selecciona "¡Esto resolvió mi problema!", entonces la pregunta pasa a marcarse como duplicada, independientemente de la cantidad de votos cosechados hasta el momento o de la reputación del usuario.
  Dado que un voto de cierre definitivo solo lo tienen los moderadores y los usuarios con medalla de oro en alguna de las etiquetas de la pregunta, internamente se usa al usuario Comunidad para que emita ese voto final.

Esto se implementó hace tres años y se describe en [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/209901) <sub>en inglés</sub>.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación. En las etiquetas en las que me muevo, es la primera vez que lo veo O_O

Comment: @Trauma jaja en verdad es raro verlo, la gente suele insistir en que "no, mi pregunta es absolutamente diferenteeee" :D

Comment: @Trauma una vez la cerramos yo y comunidad.. me hizo sentir importante.. jajaja.. igual me paso una sola vez...